# How to get all checkboxes with a class inside a specific div in jQuery?

Tags: jquery-selectors

```
<div id="table">
<input type="checkbox" class="db2applforce kon" value="15010" title="to be forced">
```

Neither of these work. It returns always 0 instead of the correct number.

```
alert($("#table").find(".kon :checkbox").length);

alert($("#table").find(":checkbox").find(".kon").length);
```

Can I do 'all in one' query?

Comment: Are you looking for a count of all checkboxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Radek,
In your selector, you should not have a space between .kon and :checkbox. This tries to find a div with the class kon and **inside of it** a checkbox. Since your checkbox **is** of the class kon, do the following instead:

```
alert($("#table").find(".kon:checkbox").length);
```

This yields the right answer. Also, you should always close your divs, i.e.:

```
<div id="table">
<input type="checkbox" class="db2applforce kon" value="15010" title="to be forced">
</div>
```

For the sake of completeness and further clarity, if your block of HTML had looked like this:

```
<div id="table">
    <div class='kon'>
        <input type="checkbox" class="db2applforce" value="15010" title="to be forced">
    </div>
</div>
```

then your first selector above would have worked, and your second one would have worked if swapped:

```
alert($("#table").find(".kon").find(":checkbox").length);
```

Comment: Thank you. Especially for the explanation. Could you recommend any reading for me to get familiar with this?

Comment: You're welcome. I read the book "jQuery: Novice to Ninja" when I started, and found it helpful and easy to understand. http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Novice-Ninja-Earle-Castledine/dp/0987153013/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1340515288&sr=8-1&keywords=jquery+for+ninjas

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for a count of all checkboxes in `#table` div.

```
alert($('#table input:checkbox.kon').length);
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="table">
    <input type="checkbox" class="db2applforce kon" value="15010" title="to be forced" checked />
    <input type="checkbox" class="db2applforce kon" value="15020" title="to be forced" />
    <input type="text" class="db2applforce kon" value="15020" title="to be forced" />    
</div>
```

### Result:

```
2
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/nDp6e/)**

Comment: I wasn't after the length. I used length to make sure that find() give correct results.